# Jersey: How to register a ExceptionMapper that omits some subclasses?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

How do I register a catch-all `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` that does **not** intercept `WebApplicationException` for which Jersey provides special handling?

**UPDATE**: I filed this feature request: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1607

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up registering a ExceptionMapper:

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.MappableContainerException;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

/**
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
@Provider
@Singleton
public class RuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException>
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException e)
    {
        if (e instanceof WebApplicationException)
        {
            // WORKAROUND: Attempt to mirror Jersey's built-in behavior.
            // @see http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1607
            WebApplicationException webApplicationException = (WebApplicationException) e;
            return webApplicationException.getResponse();
        }
        // Jetty generates a log entry whenever an exception is thrown. If we don't register an
        // ExceptionMapper, Jersey will log the exception a second time.
        throw new MappableContainerException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great starting point for creating a logging `ExceptionMapper` to log uncaught exceptions. I log those exceptions which are not instances of `WebApplicationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look how it's done in [ReXSL](http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-core/trap.html) [ExceptionTrap](https://github.com/yegor256/rexsl/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rexsl/core/ExceptionTrap.java) class. You don't register an `ExceptionMapper` to catch all exception un-caught by Jersey. Instead, you let them bubble up to the Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat), and the container will forward them to the right servlet for further handling.

The main and only purpose of `ExceptionMapper` is to convert certain business-specific exceptions to HTTP responses. In other words, let the application control exceptional flow of events. On the other hand, the purpose of servlet exception catching mechanism is to control application failover and do some post-mortem operations, like, for example, logging. In other words, `ExceptionMapper` works when you're still in control, while exception catching servlet helps when control is lost and you have to show `50x` response code to the user.

Jetty logs (through JUL) every `WebApplicationException` if status code of its encapsulated `Response` is higher than 500. Runtime exceptions are not logged by Jetty, they just bubble up to the container.

Comment: That helps, but there's a catch. If I don't register an ExceptionMapper then the exception stack trace gets logged twice: once by Jersey and once by Jetty. I only want it to get logged once. Secondly, what's the point of the ExceptionMapper mechanism if the servlet API allows this kind of error redirection?

Comment: I updated the answer. As far as I know Jetty doesn't touch runtime exceptions and let them bubble up to the container (even without logging). Provided they are not inherited from `WebApplicationException`

Comment: Unfortunately, what you wrote is not true. Jersey logs it the first time in: `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException() - The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container`. Jetty logs it a second time in `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle()`

Answer (score 1):

Extend [ExtendedExceptionMapper](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.11/org/glassfish/jersey/spi/ExtendedExceptionMapper.html) and implement `isMappable(e)`:

```
@Override
public boolean isMappable(T e) {
    return !e instanceof WebApplicationException;
}
```